# How can I detect when bootstrap-table plugin has finished rendering?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a fairly large table that is using this bootstrap-table plugin: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation. When I first load the page, the table takes a second to load the plugin's functionality, so the table appears without styling and checkboxes for that time.

```
<table class="my-table" data-toggle="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- About 1000 rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to detect when the plugin has finished rendering the table? I have tried using the `load-success.bs.table` and `post-body.bs.table` events, but they don't seen to even run on first load.

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/95804/
Each time you click Run, the table will appear without any styling and checkboxes for a split second.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the body's opacity to `0` on load, and reset it to `1` after the plugin has loaded (Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/95950/))

CSS

```
body { opacity: 0 }
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $(".my-table").bootstrapTable('hideLoading');
  $('body').css('opacity','1');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below line of code.

```
$(".my-table").bootstrapTable({
    ...
    onLoadSuccess: function() {
        // do something
    },
    ...
 });
```

Comment: The `onLoadSuccess` is the same event as the `load-success.bs.table` event that I tried already, which I saw wasn't executing when the table loads.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your JS fiddle and added a keyframe fadeIn to the CSS table.

```
.my-table {
    opacity:0;
    animation: fade-in ease 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*when the spec is finished*/
    -webkit-animation: fade-in ease 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/ 
    -moz-animation: fade-in ease 2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*FF 5+*/
    -o-animation: fade-in ease 2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*Not implemented yet*/
    -ms-animation: fade-in ease 2s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode:forwards; /*IE 10+*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/96072/